# SQL Server One Foreign Key From 2 Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, foreign-keys

Is it possible to have one foreign key that can reference 2 different tables?

Here's what I mean...

```
Create Table1(id nvarchar primary key);

Create Table2(id nvarchar primary key);

Create Table3(id nvarchar foreign key references (Table1(ID) or Table2(ID))
```

If it is not possible, is there a recommended way to work around this?

Comment: Can you provide sample data and an explanation of the data model you want to implement.

Comment: No this isn't possible. How could the constraint know which one it is referencing? The typical "work around" is to have two nullable columns Table1ID and Table2ID in Table3. And setup the foreign key constraint on each column to the relevant column.

Comment: The shown scheme allows the same value for both Table1.id and Table2.id. Imagine that there is a record in Table3 with this value - what table it is referenced on?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can have a column (or tuple of columns) to reference multiple tables as foreign keys. I [personally] call them "forking foreign keys", but that's just me.

However, those are TWO separate constraints that are enforced separately, each one all the time. You can't have an `OR` logic on it.

For example.

```
create Table1 (id nvarchar primary key);

create Table2 (id nvarchar primary key);

create Table3 (
  id nvarchar,
  constraint fk1 foreign key (id) references Table1 (ID),
  constraint fk2 foreign key (id) references Table2 (ID)
);
```

If you need an `OR` condition, then the answer to your question is "no".

Comment: Just for giving it a name...+1

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing that you want *disjoint* references to the first two tables.

You can come pretty close with persisted computed columns:

```
Create Table1 (
    id nvarchar(255)
);

Create Table2 (
    id nvarchar(255)
);

Create Table3 (
    id nvarchar(255),
    type int not null check (type in 1, 2),
    id_1 as (case when type = 1 then id end) persisted,
    id_2 as (case when type = 2 then id end) persisted,
    foreign key (id_1) references table_1(id),
    foreign key (id_2) references table_2(id)
);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=03b97dfc4b131f6667454bea6a393a2a) is a db<>fiddle.  This shows the error when the id does not properly reference the specified table.

Comment: Shouldn't `type int` be NOT NULL? Apart from that, I think this solution/workaround actually works.

Comment: @TheImpaler . . . That is a reasonable improvement.